# Need some hints for analyzer.py! I really do not know what is wrong with my code, error TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python

Here's part of my code in def analyze(self,text):

(Removed in light of academic honesty.)

Had a TypeError which is induced by the lack of () at the end of a build-in function, lower.

Conclusion: for all functions, do take note of what to include in the parentheses, else, remember to end off with (), eg. lower().

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
The code you posted merely defines `analyze` and quits without executing any active code.

Comment: Use `tokens = self.tokenizer.tokenize(text.lower())`. Currently you're passing the method, not calling it with `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a string to `tokenize` because you are not actually calling the `lower()` method.

As the error states `tokenize` is expecting a string or bytes-like object whereas you are passing to it a built in function `lower`

replace the line by this:

```
tokens = self.tokenizer.tokenize(text.lower())
```

here is what I mean:

```
type(text.lower) #=> <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

VS

```
type(text.lower()) #=> <type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
tokens = self.tokenizer.tokenize(text.lower)
```

you have inputted a built-in method to tokenize. To fix the issue, you need to change:

```
text.lower
```

to

```
text.lower()
```

This will now give you the lower case values of text as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

If text is a string (`str`) then you are passing a callable `text.lower` instead of the lowercased string `text.lower()`.